# Including vendor assets in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

My goal is to use Twitter Bootstrap with my Symfony2 project. So, in my deps file I've added the following;

```
[twitter-bootstrap]
    git=https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git
    version=v1.4.0
```

...and ran `bin/vendors install` that downloads the library to the vendors directory. Now, I have no idea on how to include any of the assets in the parent twig template. Do I need to create a custom "Bundle" or is including the vendors lib simply good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you are looking for [this bundle](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle). It does things you need.

Comment: This answer is probably what OP was looking for, but it doesn't really answer the question! I have a similar issue, trying to install jQuery UI through Composer, and I'm unable to find how should I access `vendors/components/jqueryui/[files]` in my templates.